# easiest way to style combobox's foreground color

Tags: wpf, styling

I styled `TextBlock`'s foreground to white in my global dictionary, and this style applied to `Combobox` as well which made the combobox options unreadable. I can't find an easy way to style `Combobox`'s background for windows 8 or up. So I decided that I can live with a default `Combobox` style for now but still I can't seem to find an easy solution. I tried to set the `foreground` of `Combobox`, style `TextBlock` under `Combobox.Resources` and Style `ComboBoxItem` with no luck.

It will be ideal if I can set the combobox's background to black without duplicating the whole `Combobox`'s control template. If not then it will be the best if I can style `Combobox`'s foreground in my dictionary, but I am open to solutions.

Edit: minimum example included

Dictionary1.xaml:

```
<ResourceDictionary xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
                    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
                    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApplication1">
    <Style TargetType="TextBlock">
        <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="WhiteSmoke"/>
    </Style>
</ResourceDictionary>
```

App.xaml:

```
<Application x:Class="WpfApplication1.App"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApplication1"
             StartupUri="MainWindow.xaml">
    <Application.Resources>
        <ResourceDictionary>
            <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
                <ResourceDictionary Source="Dictionary1.xaml"/>
            </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
        </ResourceDictionary>
    </Application.Resources>
</Application>
```

mainwindow.xaml

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication1.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApplication1"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525"
        Closing="Window_Closing">
    <Grid>
        <ComboBox Text="test" Height="50" Width="100" Foreground="Black">
            <ComboBox.Resources>
                <Style TargetType="ComboBoxItem">
                    <Style.Setters>
                        <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Black"/>
                    </Style.Setters>
                </Style>

                <Style TargetType="TextBlock">
                    <Style.Setters>
                        <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Black"/>
                    </Style.Setters>
                </Style>
            </ComboBox.Resources>
            <ComboBoxItem>test1</ComboBoxItem>
            <ComboBoxItem>test2</ComboBoxItem>
        </ComboBox>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

note that none of the foreground = black works. I am using windows 10.

Comment: Can you please post your ComboBox and TextBlock templates?

Comment: @DaxPandhi I did not template them(using the default one) there is only one style applied to TextBlock which is <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="WhiteSmoke"/>

Comment: I ran into the same problem a while ago. I'll find the code I used to fix it and post it in a few minutes.

Comment: cannot reproduce your problem. Please make a simple reproducible snippet for every one to test.

Comment: @KingKing minimum example included

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem here is you can only apply implicit Style on Control with unlimited scope. For other elements, the scope is limited in only DataTemplate or ControlTemplate. Implicit Style here is what defined in `Resources` and has `x:Key` not specified (in fact `x:Key` will be set to the TargetType implicitly).

The `TextBlock` you target here is the one inside `ComboBox`'s template scope so it cannot be applied with some implicit Style or some inherited style from outside. The global Style defined in App's Resources however can apply Style on all elements if there is not any other overrides.

So you have some options here. You can re-template the `ComboBoxItem`, however it requires more code. If that's not an option, you can try applying the global Style of `TextBlock` with some Trigger, something like this:

```
<Setter Property="Foreground" Value="WhiteSmoke"/>        
<Style.Triggers>
   <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding IsEnabled, 
                RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=ComboBox}}" Value="True">
      <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Black"/>
   </DataTrigger>
</Style.Triggers>
```

The `Trigger` listens to any parent of `ComboBox` and if it's enabled, the `TextBlock` will have another style (with `Foreground` set to `Black`). Of course as you see that Trigger is of the Style defined in `ResourceDictionary`. All other `TextBlock`s still have their global Style (`Foreground` set to `WhiteSmoke`).

Anyway you need to override the Style defined in `ResoureDictionary` either in the App's Resources or in the same level. `Trigger` is just a way to filter when it can be applied/overridden.

Comment: Nice trick there, I can see a lot of places where I might reapply this trick.

Comment: Works. Just to clarify for new programmers - the solution has to go in a Style.  The entire Style.Trigger tag needs to be below all other Setter lines that a style might have.

Answer (score 0):

If you are only displaying text in the ComboBox:

```
    <Style TargetType="{x:Type ComboBox}">
        <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.WindowTextBrushKey}}" />
    </Style>
```

If you want to change the background, you need to create a ControlTemplate copy. In the official Win8 and later templates, there is a problem - not in ComboBox but the ToggleButton primitive. Here is the chain of controls: ComboBoxTemplate > ToggleButton > ToggleButtonTemplate. However, the `TemplateBinding` to Background and other brushes is NOT present in the TogglebuttonTemplate so any changes to the background are not propagated down to the ToggleButton's children. The only way is to create a copy of the control and hook up that missing piece by TemplateBinding the ToggleButton template. However, I'm not sure if the ComboBox will retain the native OS look on other versions of Windows.

I tried overriding the ToggleButton primitive, but it does not have the custom template that the ComboBox's ToggleButton uses.

Comment: I'm trying something else. I'm assuming the Combo is not editable.

Comment: This is silly and you may have already tried it, but what about modifying the Combo's `Foreground` (or binding) to Black or whatever? Had to ask. :)

Comment: If none of those are working, the problem might be elsewhere. If you have VS2015 you can use the WPF visual debugging tool to see where the color is coming from. Otherwise you can use Snoop.

Comment: The color comes from the dictionary style, I can see that from the Visualization tool. But I don't get why the style inside Combobox.Resource did not override it.